# Pull data froma third table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
<!-- language: sql -->

     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempT') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempT

 BEGIN
SELECT t1.id_Col, t2.route into #tempT 
FROM soTran t1 
    LEFT JOIN armast t2
            ON t1.custno = t2.custno
    WHERE t1.orDate between DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(day,0, GETDATE())
EXCEPT ( SELECT a.id_col, c.route
        FROM sotran a
            INNER JOIN sotran b
        ON a.custno = b.custno
            LEFT JOIN armast c
        ON a.custno = c.custno
        WHERE a.ordate = b.ordate AND a.item = 'PLO' AND b.item <> 'PLO') 
EXCEPT ( SELECT b.id_col, c.route
    FROM sotran a
        INNER JOIN sotran b
        ON a.custno = b.custno
            LEFT JOIN armast c
        ON a.custno = c.custno
        WHERE a.ordate = b.ordate AND a.item = 'PLO' AND b.item <> 'PLO' ) 
SELECT DISTINCT sono, q1.custno, item, q1.ordate, q1.salesmn, q2.company,(select route1 from #tempT)
FROM soTran q1 
LEFT JOIN arcust q2
ON q1.custno = q2.custno
WHERE q1.id_col in (select id_col from #tempT) AND item = 'PLO' --AND q3.ordate      between DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(day,0, GETDATE())
        ORDER BY custno, ordate

 DROP TABLE #tempT
 END
```

I am trying to pull a route ID from the armast table that goes with the data this query is pulling.  For some reason it is not pulling the correct ID's.

Comment: weird, the `SELECT` use in the `EXCEPT`s use the same columns than the outer `SELECT`. Are you sure you are using that exact same query?

Comment: I updated it....figured out why I was getting the error.  Now just need to figure out how to return the correct route ID's